# Free alternative to Atlassian Greenhopper/PivotalTracker?

Tags: project-management, jira, agile, sprint, pivotaltracker

I'm working with my brother on a website idea we have, and we'd like to use a tool to plan sprints and assign estimates to individual tickets.

Atlassian's JIRA+Greenhopper looks fantastic but costs $20/month and at this stage we're just validating our idea and would rather not spend money on a tool if we can avoid it.

Are there any free alternatives to these tools?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.asitrack.com.

Comment: Atm, you can try Jira for a month, for free... And host the service yourselves, for 20 dollar (total)... (I'm considering) Taiga is nice indeed!

Comment: One more alternative to be considered Krosswall ( http://www.krosswall.com ). It’s design to bridging the GAP between Agile in THEORY and Agile in IMPLEMENTATION.

Answer (score 64):

Taiga is 100% free and has all the features that comes with something like JIRA.

http://taiga.io/

It even has a burn-down chart! So that's a win!

Here's a site with a nice overview of what Taiga integrates with and real developer opinions on the tool.

http://stackshare.io/taiga

Comment: It's a very nice pm system. However, it should be noted that Taiga is free for public projects only. Currently, private projects will be free during the Beta phase until July 2015. There will be a cost associated with a private project afterwards.

Comment: Taiga is open source. Private projects by cloud hosted taiga will have a cost (not sure if July 2015) but users can always self-host their own Taiga.

Comment: @Xaviju Taiga is pretty hard to setup

Comment: @Nn-bhargav we have our online docs https://taigaio.github.io/taiga-doc/dist/#_setup_production_environment, a support@taiga.io email and a community mailing list at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/taigaio to help you out with installation, and some users created scripts and dockers to make it easier.

Comment: Is it free only for public projects?

Comment: At the time of writing, (2016-02-24) Taiga does allow free accounts to have private projects.

Comment: Looks good and has Kanban and Scum, but is very restrictive and you need your ticket workflow to be as they designed it. For example: you have to work with story and with subtasks in Sprint, but you cannot add bug or engancement unless is linked to a story. Also you cannot see all tickes types (bug, story, task, enhancement) on same page. On kanban view you can only see tasks(not stories). I found it to restrictive and will look for other tools. Check discussion from their project page: https://github.com/taigaio/taiga-front/issues/797

Answer (score 12):

Trello is a good tool for creating task boards and tracking work for small teams.

https://trello.com/

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't track time and does not show addition of time for N tickets in a sprint.

Comment: He he, Steven, I also use Trello, and for very very small teams, including non-programmers, it is good option, but I have worked with JIRA for a while in past, and yeah - branch traking combining with Stash is great value! :)

Comment: Trello itself may not have time tracking, but you can always use a Chrome extension to add that feature. Something like `Plus for Trello`: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/plus-for-trello-time-trac/gjjpophepkbhejnglcmkdnncmaanojkf

Comment: Trello is terrible for scrum. It's a simple task board. No more no less.

Answer (score 8):

I get this question a lot as a Scrum Trainer.

I strongly recommend Index Cards and a Physical Scrum Board.  While it won't calculate time addition for you, that task is trivial and the 'information at a glance' that a Scrum Board offers is hugely beneficial.

If you absolutely HAVE to have an electronic board, try Visual Studio Online (TFS in the cloud) which, at present, is free for up to 5 users.

Comment: Yes, the best free alternative is the Physical Scrum board! And calculations are not so hard. @Serg you can use a google spreadsheet for those.
  It is pretty easy to build your sheet to calculate everything for you - it is just basic math.

Comment: you can not do this for distributed teams

Comment: We need a physical board, but we're distributed. My first mental draft is: 
1) Use Trello to virtually optimise the Product Backlog  2) Take photos of the physical board and post them back to Trello or somewhere common. 3) Product Owner (wherever they are) is in charge of doing that. Ideally, there is one source of truth for the board, but obviously it can be copied by hand form another location.

Comment: @jtrein  I suggest that distributed teams are still best served by physical scrum boards. This can be achieved through simple use of 24/7 webcam, collaboration and communication, all of which help break down the barriers that exist between geographically dislocated team members.  Some references: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/virtual-teams-worse-than-i-thought-patrick-lencioni (Patrick Lencioni)
 https://webgate.ltd.uk/electronic-scrum-board-vs-physical-scrum-board/ (Disclaimer: I wrote this article)

Answer (score 4):

Another option (We use Jira) would be YouTRACK. http://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/buy/

It is free for up to 10 users and seems to offer pretty much the same functionality.

DISCLAIMER: I have never used YouTRACK on any level.  IntelliJ is a great product though.

Comment: No private projects in the free version.

Answer (score 3):

For Agile project management, I have used extensive [Thoughtworks - Mingle](http://www.thoughtworks.com/products/mingle-agile-project-management) 
It's free for 5 users.
Another good alternative could be [agilefant](http://agilefant.com/). Agilefant offers a free and open source product that can be downloaded and deployed into your own private cloud.

If you are looking open source project management, which you can host on your own, the following list could be useful:

- [ProjectLibre](http://www.projectlibre.org/) is a java based ms-project rich client alternative
- [LibrePlan](http://www.libreplan.com/) is a rich client and based on [these videos](http://www.libreplan.com/info/documentation/) it seems like ms-project and includes hours spend by user on task, collaboration was not visible in the videos
- [OpenProject](https://www.openproject.org/) is a web based software with [features such as issues, time lines (gantt chart), calendars, meeting notes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYsZn8R1q_k) and more
- [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) is a web based software using the Ruby on Rails framework that includes issues, work log, a wiki and a gantt chart and more.

Comment: It seems to me based on my 1h research that Project Libe and LibrePlan are more like ms project and offer little collaboration. Where OpenProject and Redmine are more like jira with collaboration features.

Comment: valid point., thanks for updating the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also check TargetProcess (http://www.targetprocess.com/pricing/) it's free for 5 users

i use it for three months and it's very good

Answer (score 1):

I used Trello (http://trello.com) and Mingle (http://getmingle.io) on two different projects. Trello is great for tracking tasks and collaborating for small team. My trello project team had 3 members, we were distributed. We also use Google drives to track unstructured information. My mingle project team have more than 10 people, and used it for years. Team love using it for standup on big touch TV and different roles (BA/QA/PM) like it because you have have your own workspace track different tasks and sometime build their own report).

Comment: Trello is not so robust

Comment: @NBhargav -- Trello can be more robust with the help of extensions like `Plus for Trello`.

Answer (score 0):

[IceScrum](http://icescrum.com). 
It's open source and you can run on your own server.
The best open source project planning in my opinion!

Answer (score -1):

https://www.teamwork.com/pricing

**"If you don't pay after the 30 day free trial you can still use Teamwork Projects free forever"**

"We also have a Free Forever Plan with 2 projects and 100mb space"